# Variable Anchor tags inside a variable post Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

i have a very long article created by a user in Wordpress , i want to show a navigation on every article page with links to the titles of the current article.

```
e.g: 
<h1 id='title1'>Title 1</h1>
bla bla bla
<h1 id='title2'>Title 2</h1>
bla bla

my navigation on this page would be <a href="#title1">Anchor link to title 1</a>
```

The example above is how you would hardcode it, but my article text is obviously variable and so are my links, what is the best way to tackle this with php?

**Edit: the situation is not exactly like the example, the user puts text into a wordpress text editor field and doesnt want to write html tags, so the navigation needs to be filled with the titles that the user has put in the text field and those link to the variable titles on the page. (with an anchor i assume)**

the functionality would be something like Microsoft word:
[image]

Comment: That's maybe a bit too obvious but I have to ask, why user can't put the link himself using the link button so he select the right id to link? No need for him to write html for that.

Comment: this can be the solution , but i like to avoid it because the user is inputting very large articles (articles related to the law) he would just have to import these articles via the wordpress importer or copy-paste , having him go trough every title to add an id is something he is going to complain about after the first week. Also i have a golden rule for all my projects , dont give a user the possibility to break functionality of a website.

Comment: I guess we could elaborate a solution based on [the_content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter to add the ID on the title using [sanitize_title](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title), but how do you plan to know which link need to be changed to the right ID? Or should you just generate an anchor menu as the top of the page, in a wikipedia way?

Comment: I would think something like only h1 tags need to be links. i want my endresult simular the way microsoft word does it: http://cdn.ttgtmedia.com/rms/computerweekly/photogalleries/241181/2338_20_the-navigation-pane-in-word-lets~-as-navigate-or-browse-page-by-page.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [filter the content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) in order to target the different titles, add an ID in a form of a slug using [`sanitize_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title) on each of them and build a hierarchical array of those titles in order to display the anchor menu on top of the post.

I just wrote this filter for the example, but it is totally not tested so you may have to debug it a bit and change it depending of your needs. Please note that it works for a 3 level hierarchy maximum.

```
function add_anchor_menu($content) {
    // First you may want to do some check here to see if this filter should be trigger on the current post...

    $arrayTitles = array();

    // Generate the ids...
    $content = preg_replace_callback(
        '#<h([1-3])>(.*?)<\/h[1-3]>#',
        function($matches) {
            $id = sanitize_title($matches[2]);
            $meta = array('id' => $id, 'title' => $matches[2], 'childs' => array());
            if((int)$matches[1] == 1) {
                array_push($arrayTitles, $meta);
            } elseif((int)$matches[1] == 2) {
                end($arrayTitles);
                array_push($arrayTitles[key($arrayTitles)]['childs'], $meta);
            } else {
                end($arrayTitles);
                end($arrayTitles[key($arrayTitles)]['childs']);
                array_push($arrayTitles[key($arrayTitles)]['childs'][key($arrayTitles[key($arrayTitles)])], $meta);
            }
            return '<h' . $matches[1] . ' id="' . $id . '">' . $matches[2] . '</h' . $matches[1] . '>';
        },
        $content
    );

    // And generate the menu...
    if(count($arrayTitles) > 0) {
        $menu = '<ul id="anchor-menu">';
        foreach($arrayTitles as $level1) {
            $menu .= '<li>';
            $menu .= '<a href="#' . $level1['id'] . '">' . $level1['title'] . '</a>';
            if(count($level1['childs']) > 0) {
                $menu .= '<ul>';
                foreach($level1['childs'] as $level2) {
                    $menu .= '<li>';
                    $menu .= '<a href="#' . $level2['id'] . '">' . $level2['title'] . '</a>';
                    if(count($level2['childs']) > 0) {
                        $menu .= '<ul>';
                        foreach($level2['childs'] as $level3) {
                            $menu .= '<li><a href="#' . $level3['id'] . '">' . $level3['title'] . '</a></li>';
                        }
                        $menu .= '</ul>';
                    }
                    $menu .= '</li>';
                }
                $menu .= '</ul>';
            }
            $menu .= '</li>';
        }
        $menu .= '<ul>';
        $content = $menu . $content;
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_anchor_menu');
```

Comment: this looks great, will try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

In your mark up

```
<h1 id="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">Title 1</h1>
<a href="#<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">Anchor link to title 1</a>
```

You should esc_url() in the href attribute as well.

Comment: it is not really that simple, that was just an example. The <h1> text is placed by someone else , he puts text in the text editor of wordpress, the user who puts it in, also doenst understand html so he just needs to type the alrticle and my menu will be filled out with the user inputted titles and those titles link to the relative titles inside the page

Comment: Perhaps you want to modify the post data before it's saved to the DB via a wordpress hook/filter like [wp_insert_post_data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data) or [content_save_pre](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_save_pre)

Comment: @pbaldauf adding something to the content before it's saved to the DB sound like its a good direction , i'm not really sure how to implement that tho, i have a good understanding of php but i'm fairly new to wordpress so i dont have much experience with those hooks